# How do I reference the settings of my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

In the main `Plugin.php` file of my plugin, I can retrieve the plugin's settings like this:

```
$this->getSettings()
```

**How do I retrieve those same settings from elsewhere in the plugin?**

I want to reference those setting from my `Service.php` file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings()
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Ben Parizek answer, here is a full example code to get value of a "foo" setting from a "bar" plugin, using magic get methods.

```
$pluginSettings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('bar')->getSettings();
$foo = $pluginSettings->foo;
```

Comment: Where the magic exists, it's worth using... Thanks!