# How does a plugin include it's own config options?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

When building a plugin, how does one define user editable config files? Would it be better to create a settings UI in the plugin and have the user edit those variables in the CP? Or is there a way to do it properly with a config file?

The reason I want to opt for a config option is so the value can be localized for the specific environment to set different options. I need to add the ability to define a public directory that will be used to store generated images and obviously that path could be different on local and production environments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a `config.php` file in the root of your plugin's folder (`craft/plugins/pluginhandle/config.php`) that specifies the default values of your config items by returning an array of key value pairs for config settings and values.

If a user wants to change any of those settings, they can add a `pluginhandle.php` config file to `craft/config/pluginhandle.php` that returns an array with the overridden key value pairs.

From your plugin, if you call:

`craft()->config->get('key', 'pluginhandle')`

then Craft will return the user supplied value, if it exists, and fallback on the plugin supplied default value, if it does not.

Also worth nothing that all of Craft's [multi-environment config stuff](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) will work in this context for the plugin, too.

Comment: That's really helpful to know!

Comment: Is this in the docs?

Comment: Does multi-enviroment config really work in this context? Does not seem to be working for me. This answer also seems to imply it does not work: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12778/plugin-multi-environment-config-not-working?lq=1

Comment: @KristianJ. It works in the sense you can override your default plugin values (that live in `plugins/pluginHandle/config.php`) in the multi-environment config part of `craft/config/pluginHandle.php`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use plugin settings to store these kinds of values. Then in your plugin files (controller, services etc.) you could call up the settings and adjust your output as needed.

```
craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings()
```

As for asset paths and your site path, you can keep all of those relative by using the URL helper functions like 
`{{ url('assets/build/css/main.css') }}` and `UrlHelper::getUrl('/')` depending on where you are working.

Here's a related post - [How do I reference the settings of my plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/418/how-do-i-reference-the-settings-of-my-plugin)