# Plugin Settings: Attribute Types, and how to receive

Tags: plugin-development, php, services, settings

I have two small arrays I want to store in my plugin settings, though I'm stuck at what the AttributeType:: should be, as well as how to retrieve the actual values. The arrays I want to store look like:

```
'active_features' => [
     'change_team' => false,
     'change_series' => false,
     'change_user_settings' => false,
],
```

In my plugin file (pluginHandlePlugin.php) I see I can do something like this:

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'pluginSettings1'   => array(AttributeType::Mixed, 'active_features' => array('change_team' => false, 'change_series' => false, 'change_user_settings' => false)),
    );
}
```

And getting those values through the service file works like:

```
public function getPluginSettings()
{
$plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginHandle');
$settings = $plugin->getSettings();

return $settings;
}
```

Which works, and returns the object for me. However I'm unable to get to the actual key/values from the original array, I've tried:

```
return $settings->pluginSettings1;
```

But that returns NULL

So, how do I retrieve the keys/values, and also, what is the best AttributeType:: to set for this? I've looked around for AttributeType:: options and details but didn't find anything.

Any help would be GREAT! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as accessing the value of the setting, try:

```
$plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginHandle');
$plugin->getSettings()->getAttribute('pluginSettings1');
```

If you need to access your settings throughout your services file you might also create a global variable.

```
class PluginHandleService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{
    public $settings = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->settings = $this->initSettings();
    }

    private function initSettings()
    {
        $plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginHandle');

        $settings = array();
        $settings['pluginSettings1'] = $plugin->getSettings()->getAttribute('pluginSettings1');

        return $settings;
    }

    // other service methods

}
```

Which you can then access like this:

```
$this->settings['pluginSettings1']
```

Thanks to André Elvan for help on [setting up a constructor](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/3028/784).

**Update**

As far as assigning a value however, I think you may have to use the 'default' property. In the past I have successfully done this with strings like so:

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'pluginSettings1' => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => "value"),
}
```

I presume you could do the same with 'Mixed', although never tried:

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'pluginSettings1' => array(AttributeType::Mixed, 'default' => 'active_features' => array('change_team' => false, 'change_series' => false, 'change_user_settings' => false))),
}
```

It might make more sense to break the array into individual settings, however.

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
        'change_team'          => array(AttributeType::Bool, 'default' => 'false',
        'change_series'        => array(AttributeType::Bool, 'default' => 'false',
        'change_user_settings' => array(AttributeType::Bool, 'default' => 'false',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

I think there's a problem with the array structure I am using for "defineSettings()":

Because $settings['change_team'] returns: PHP notice "Trying to get property of non-object", and  $settings['pluginSettings1'] returns: array(1) { ["pluginSettings1"]=> NULL }

Comment: I wasn't really paying attention to how you were assigning the values. I updated the answer — hopefully this is on the right track.

Comment: The last suggestion (breaking array into individual settings) made more sense and after trying it, I was able to get things working perfectly. I can't thank you enough for helping out with this man!