# Plugin Multi-Environment config not working

Tags: plugin-development, config, multi-environment

I have set up the plugin's multi-environment configuration as outlined in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2000/3584).

The `config.php` file for the plugin is as follows:

```
<?php

return array(
    // All
    '*' => array(
    ),

    // Development
    '.domain.dev' => array(
        'apiKey' => 'APIKEYDEVVALUE'
    ),

    // Staging
    'dev.domain.com' => array(
        'apiKey' => 'APIKEYSTAGINGVALUE'
    ),

    // Production
    'dev.domain.com' => array(
        'apiKey' => 'APIKEYPRODVALUE'
    ),
);
```

But calling `craft()->config->get('apiKey', 'pluginhandle')` returns `null`.

If I `var_dump(craft()->config)` I can see that the config file for the plugin is loaded by craft.

What am I missing?  Please let me know if I can provide any more useful info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're putting the multi-environment config code in your `plugins/pluginHandle/config.php` file, which is just meant to supply default plugin config values.

Users can set custom values in `craft/config/pluginHandle.php` which is where the multi-environment logic would also go.