# How do I reference the settings of my plugin from a template?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, settings

[This question and answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/418/how-do-i-reference-the-settings-of-my-plugin) explains how to access a plugin's settings from elsewhere in the plugin's PHP code.

How would I access these settings from within a template? Or this impossible and I'd have to pass the values into the template when rendering it? ie, in a Controller action:

```php
$settings = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings();
$templateVars = array(
    'foo' => $settings->foo,
);
$this->renderTemplate('myPlugin/templateName', $templateVars);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there's a build in way, but you can set up a [template variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) that returns the settings model.

```
class MyPluginVariable
{
    public function settings()
    {
        return craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings();
    }
}
```

Then access it in your template.

```
{% set settings = craft.myPlugin.settings %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carl. Looks like that's the closest I'm going to get.

Answer (score 6):

In more recent versions of Craft 2.x (I forget when it was added), you can simply do this without needing a plugin:

```
craft.config.get('setting', 'plugin')
```

Where `'plugin'` is the name of your plugin's config file (sans `.php`).

If you want to do this in Craft 3, you'd do:

```
craft.app.getModule('pluginHandle').getSettings().mySetting
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the only way to get plugin info back (in a template) is by doing:

```
{% set plugin = craft.plugins.getPlugin('PluginHandle') %}
```

This returns an instance of `PluginVariable` for your plugin, so you have access to any method detailed in `craft/app/variables/PluginVariable.php` ([the craft class reference](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/variables/PluginVariable))

It looks like the `getSettings()` function isn't exposed in this, so I don't think its possible.

I could be wrong and there could be a way, but I couldn't figure it out from a quick look over the code :/

Comment: Thanks Alec - that's as far as I'd got with looking around, so good to have it confirmed!